# Python: strange list behaviour when initialising empty nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Could someone explain why:

```
b = 10*[[]]
b[0].append(3)
```

b now is:

```
[[3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
```

but if I do:

```
b = [[] for _ in range(10)]
b[0].append(3)
```

b is now:

```
[[3], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Also note that

```
10*[[]] == [[] for [] in range(10)]
```

returns

```
True
```

(Tested in Python 3.6.1)

Comment: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/2301450)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 because:
    >>> b = 10*[[]]
    >>> b[0] is b[1]
    True
    >>> b = [[] for _ in range(10)]
    >>> b[0] is b[1]
    False
    >>>
```